# Set checkbox as read-only using Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am currently using a `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox />` and I was wondering if there is a way to make it read only.

Basically, I would like you to be able to make it open up a sublist of check boxes and the original checkbox would only show the checkmark if any of the other checkboxes are checked.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Try putting the `disabled` attribute to `true`. After when one of the textboxes below is clicked call a server method with `<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.checkListener}" update="generalCheckbox">`. Here you check what's checkboxes state and you set your general checkbox value depending on this.

Comment: I'm doubting that the question title matches the question real matters. I think what you ask in title is covered by just `disable` attribute, but in the content you're going one step further.

Answer (score 6):

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{formBean.value1}" disabled="true"/>
```

This will disable the element. I used to change CSS by primeface skinning if required.

Bind the property with some Boolean variable in manage bean. Refresh/ Reload the component on  completion of the event [ according to the requirement ] that is changing the Boolean variable.

Comment: I think the problem with disabled is how it looks.

Answer (score 3):

Setting

```
disabled="true"
```

solves the issue, that this checkbox cannot be edited anymore, but it is very pale, and it's look-and feel don't conform page style.
I used the following trick to make this like an ordinary (not disabled) component:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui-chkbox div').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
});
```

This removes "disabled" style from all primefaces checkboxes on the page. You can easily adjust it only to the components you need.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me, and it's look-and feel is ok:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{beanc.value}" onchange="return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default. You can disable the checkbox and use css as follows:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.value}" disabled="true" styleClass="readonly" />
```

And the following css so that the box does not appear disabled.

```
.ui-selectbooleancheckbox.readonly .ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-disabled
{
 opacity: 1;
}
```